# Decided to install an SSD in an old laptop. All went havoc

Tags: boot, system-installation, ssd

My old HP laptop had 2 HDDs; system, and data backup. I decided to upgrade the system to an SSD.

Removed the backup drive, installed the SSD as drive 1 and the HD as drive 2. Used Clonezilla in a flash drive to mirror the 650G HD to the 1T SSD.
All went fine, all partitions were mirrored: But the SSD would not boot.

Ran boot repair, nothing.

Removed SSD, moved HDD to drive 1 and again won't boot.

Used an Ubuntu install flash to format/reinstall Ubuntu. Nothing was done with the Home folder.

Now it boots, but I cannot access the data in the HDD.  SUDO CHOWN does't work.

The data is there, as Gparted shows over 150G as the size of home, but Nautilus shows only some KB.

Note: by the time of system reinstall using the flash drive, I could read the content of /home.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT

1 - The SSD is on line. Same method as used with the HD, so no BIOS etc problem.

2 - I tried many suggestions I found on the WEB to take ownership of home. Basically SUDO CHOWN USER:USER

3 - Now, for some reason, the partitions in the SSD have changed,  they will have to be formatted.
Thus, the remaining problem is how to read the HD data.

Thanks, guys,

Here's Oldfred requested summary (only the HD, the SSD will be reformatted):

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6VbmQGN87z/

Comment: Please click [edit] above and add to your question exactly what you typed to try to take ownership of the files on the HDD and what its result was. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: If you had both old drive & cloned new drive still installed, that would be a problem as you cannot have duplicate UUIDs. And SSD need AHCI in BIOS/UEFI for trim to work. SSD may need firmware update also. Is BIOS/UEFI latest version from vendor? Also post this: `lsblk -f` with both drives plugged in from Uubntu live installer.

Comment: That was before the Ubuntu reinstall in the HD. They had the same UUID, but no more. Even before formatting the SSD, I was able to boot with both drives on line using the HD as the reinstall in the HD changed the UUID.

Comment: If you reinstalled, you will have to update your `fstab` to point to the partition(s) on the data drive.

Comment: It keeps getting more complicated. We need details. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair